# mysql update query with select as criteria

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql

```
UPDATE reservation SET flag = "1" WHERE ipAddress = (SELECT ipAddress FROM reservation WHERE endDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Im trying to use this query for changing flag column of those entries in reservation table whose date has expired. The flag column is by default 0. so im trying to change expired once to 1 for my identification.

Im getting the following error.

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'reservation' for updatein FROM clause
```

Can someone suggest a solution to this problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using the same table in the subselect, you can probably omit the subselect altogether.
why dont you use the following instead

```
UPDATE reservation 
SET flag = "1" 
WHERE endDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: oh man i was simply trying to over complicate things!! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the inner `SELECT`. You just need to update the `flag` status based on the `endDate`

```
UPDATE reservation 
SET flag = "1" 
WHERE endDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```